# WEKA: How can i re-train my existing model with new set of observations(batch update) at a time instead of single instance at a time in java?

Tags: java, weka

I have data set of size six million, i'm considering five million as train-data set and 1 million as test data set.

I want to split again that training set into five - one million data sets.
Initially i want to build my model with first one million data set, on top of it i want to re-train my model with remaining four sets of train data. Simply i want to  train my model in split-wise manner instead giving whole train data set at a time. Is it possible? if possible what API's i have to use and 
How can i do that using weka library?

Following are the API's i want to use in my code.

I will use buildClassifier(Instances intances) for initial model build.
so can i call the buildClassifier() again and again for remaining four sets of data? is it re-train my model ? or every time builds new model with new dataset? if possible how can i code for it?

if above case not possible with buildClassifier(), i want to use updateClassifier(Instance instance) which is taking one instance at a time but I don't want to re-train my model in sequential manner. I want to re-train in mini batch mode (giving a set instances at a time). How i can do that using weka? or is there any another java API which takes a set of instances to update classifier in weka library?

Answer (score 0):

`buildClassifier` builds a new classifier, it does not update the current classifier.